# Regression with common predictor for independent variable

Tags: regression, correlation, predictor

Assume I have a regression, where y and one of the dependent variables (may) share a predictor. For example, if I wanted to check for a correlation between occurrences of heart attacks (age-dependent) and occurrences of cancer (also age-dependent). My aim is to check if these are inherently connected, and (in this example) independently so of age.

Would the simple inclusion of age as a covariate be sufficient correction for this shared predictor? i.e.

`heart_attack ~ age + cancer`

or would it be in any way more correct to first run a regression of

`cancer ~ age`

and then use the residual in a second regression?

`heart_attack ~ age + cancer_residual`

For more context, I'm planning to run a multitude of regressions (both linear and logistic) and the common predictor may or may not apply for the independent variable.

Any insights are greatly appreciated.